# Are there any good movies involving mathematics or probability?

Tags: probability, references

Can you suggest some good movies which involve math, probabilities etc? One example is [21](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21_%282008_film%29). I would also be interested in movies that involve algorithms (e.g. text decryption). In general "geeky" movies with famous scientific theories but no science fiction or documentaries. Thanks in advance!

Comment: nice idea for a collection ! @mods: Beside cw maybe renaming to "movies every statistician should have seen" or something like that ?

Comment: @steffen Thx. Better to flag the question for mods attention in the future (we aren't notified with @mods).

Comment: By the way, I found this page, which might add some movies to the collection: http://world.std.com/~reinhold/mathmovies.html

Comment: Nothing that will inspire anybody to take up mathematics. Stick to books.

Comment: @Emre Maybe. But nevertheless it is entertaining for those who already deal with math (even more if the movie is presenting things wrong or with exaggeration).

Comment: You can't really say what will or will not inspire someone to do something, and that includes mathematics.  Plenty of stories of famous scientists and mathematicians who were inspired by some hokey thing they saw on TV.

Comment: Counts as a book hoping to become a movie with lots of (stealthy) math in it: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1740916372/maths-thriller

Comment: "Mission Impossible"

Comment: Not a movie, but [Sweet Tooth](https://www.significancemagazine.com/science/432-ian-mcewan-sinks-his-sweet-tooth-into-the-monty-hall-problem) features a writer whose attempt to build a plot around the Monty Hall problem fails because he hasn't properly understood the intuition behind the correct solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Pi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138704/)

Comment: An absorbing story and one I'd recommend, but it referred to math rather than truly involding math.  I'd say the same thing about the tv show Numb3rs.

Comment: @rolando2 I eagerly await the day when a movie can be made about some foundational mathematician or field of mathematics which is both interesting to the public and adequately involves math. I don't think a 2 hour epic soliloquy of Galois on the night before his fatal duel would stand up to Iron Man IV, but who knows? This is why the only movies about mathematicians are about insane mathematicians.

Comment: Maybe "life of Alexander Grothendieck"  could be made into a blockbuster movie?

Answer (score 13):

'[A Beautiful Mind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268978/)' naturally has a bit of game theory in it.

Comment: one can also use this to generate discussion on spurious correlation

Answer (score 12):

MONEYBALL! 
It's a movie where the statisticians win!

This is probably the most inspiring major motion picture about the power of quantitative methods.  (if only because the plot is a little formulaic). And it shows quantitative methods (sabrmetrics) eventually coming to dominate over the backward and untested techniques of the dinosaurs of baseball.

Comment: Captain Holt's reaction to that movie pretty much sums it all: http://www.mit.edu/~jjenny/brooklyn99-statistical-analysis-cc.gif

Comment: The Oakland Athletics lost in the playoffs, and so did not appear in the World Series in 2002; indeed they have not this millennium.

Answer (score 11):

Not a movie, but a TV series:
[Numb3rs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numb3rs)

Answer (score 11):

[The mathematical movie database](http://www.qedcat.com/moviemath/index.html) has some great suggestions with over 800 movies (though most tenuously linked to maths) already listed. *In the navy*, from 1941, is probably my favourite.

Comment: Cooooooooooooooooooool!

Comment: Awesomeeee, gratitude B-]

Answer (score 10):

[N Is a Number: A Portrait of Paul Erdős](http://zalafilms.com/films/nisanumber.html)

Answer (score 10):

[Proof](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0377107/) was pretty good.

Comment: I think this has been the most "authentic" depiction of mathematicians I've seen in a movie that's very good and entertaining.

Answer (score 9):

[The Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_%28film%29)

Comment: good one. It has a not so good sequel called Hypercube.

Comment: @mpiktas, I never did see Hypercube, and it does not sound like I should :-) I saw The Cube some ten years ago and found it pretty entertaining.

Answer (score 8):

*[21](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478087/)* - based on the book Bringing Down the House (MIT Blackjack team)

Near the beginning they discuss the Monty Hall Problem.  However after that there isn't much actual math/probability.

Comment: The story is somewhat based on the real lives of some very notable mathematicians, I believe Stone and Kalman, who developed these gaming strategies.

Comment: too bad the movie is terrible... there was a tv documentary based on the same thing that was much better.

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen this yet, but it seems somewhat geeky:
[Fermat's Room](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1016301/)

Comment: It's not particularly geeky - it is a Spanish thriller (and like all thrillers has some implausible plot lines to move the story along and resolve it at the end) with a few logic puzzles using numbers.  If you want to solve the puzzles yourself, a pause button might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

There are several movie versions of *[Flatland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)*. And there's *The Great $\pi$/e Debate*.

Answer (score 4):

Early in [The Social Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Social_Network#Plot) begins with a one night hackathon where Mark Zuckerberg uses the [Elo rating system algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) to

> ... create a website that rates the attractiveness of female students
>   when compared to each other. ... in a few hours, using an algorithm for
>   ranking chess players supplied by his best friend, Eduardo Saverin, he
>   creates a website called "FaceMash," where students can choose which of
>   two girls presented at a time is more
>   attractive.

However, much of the rest of the movie is devoted to episodes of hacking, corporate politics, lawsuits, escapades, Zuckerberg's interpersonal problems, etc.  But, I found it quite fascinating, overall.  A great geek movie.

Answer (score 3):

[Good Will Hunting](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) is also a classic. Discrete mathematics at MIT.

Comment: Their depiction of maths is horrid.

Answer (score 3):

The documentary about Andrew Wiles proof of Fermat's Last Theorem is fantastic:
http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/proof/

Available on youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FnXgprKgSE

Answer (score 2):

[BBC Horizon - The Bible Code](http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/horizon/2003/biblecode.shtml). It shows, that whatever codes people found  in Bible, so far they didn't prove to be statistically significant.

Answer (score 2):

[The Man Who Knew Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Knew_Infinity_(film)) is based on the life of Srinivasa Ramanujan.

It's a beautiful movie directed by Matthew Brown. Mathematicians [Manjul Bhargava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjul_Bhargava) and [Ken Ono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Ono) collaborated on the film.

Answer (score 1):

Rounders. A very watchable drama about poker players.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128442/

Answer (score 1):

There is a published a documentary about [Srinivasa Ramanujan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2861842/) whose life, as we know, is tremendously interesting. However, the film is Indian and I haven't actually seen it. I recall an Indian math historian speaking about this film at our university colloquium several years ago. He boasted, "Ben Kingsley was interested in depicting Ramanujan but was turned down for the role because he was only *half* Indian". As a mixed race individual, I felt a mixture of anger and pity. The latter because they basically turned down the opportunity to make a movie that would attract anyone's attention.

Answer (score 1):

[Sofia Kovalevskaya](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264950/) - biopic about Russian female mathematician. You don't have too many movies about these folks. One of the recent ones is The Imitation Game about Alan Turing, a British mathematician and computer scientist (allegedly) murdered by his government.

Comment: I had not heard the theory that Alan Turing was murdered. The most likely scenarios are suicide or accidental poisoning. https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-18561092#:~:text=What%20is%20well%20known%20and,apple%20on%20his%20bedside%20table.

Comment: @JohnL here's one link: https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-18561092 the theory that he was murdered by the government is quite popular in academic circles. at least that's how i learned about it when in academia, and it was one factor that convinced me to never work on classified projects.

Comment: Also, to me even if the British government did not outright kill him, what they did to him is not much different from murder. chemically castrating someone for being a gay is a crime in itself, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

[Stand and Deliver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_and_Deliver) is a good film about the Bolivian-born math teacher [Jaime Escalante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Escalante). Inspiring! [See this commentary](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=125380015)

Answer (score 0):

12 angry men (1957, with Henry Fonda): a great film about a decision procedure and the strength of evidences

Comment: A great movie, but not particularly centered on maths.

Answer (score -1):

[travelling salesman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1801123/) is a good one.

Comment: From the trivia entry for that link http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1801123/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv  "No consultant in any field related to the storyline has been listed, and many of the statements regarding mathematics are incorrect. This film is about morality, it is not intended to be a true depiction of mathematics or computer science."